# Rails - a model belongs_to other models single reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Simple association question.
I have a Location model with the following fields:
- Name
- Address
- Lat
- Long

This model should have many "locationables".

Ok. I also have the following models:

```
Lodging
has_one location (location id)

Transportation
has_one start_location, class_name: location
has_one end_location, class_name: location
```

So, in this situation I should have a "belongs_to" in my Location model? Or I don't need anything and just put "belongs_to" in each other model?. That seems wrong, right? It seems so simple yet my head is not solving it.

Answer (score 0):

To create proper cross reference you need to have either `::belongs_to` or `::has_and_belongs_to_many` associations in a class to initiate a direct reference. The first creates `class_id` field (and attribute readers) in the class, the second additional cross reference join table named like "`class_klasses`". If you have no eithers, you can properly setup the reference by tying the classes, because `::has_one`, and `::has_many` just use back references, not direct ones. So you will need something like follows:

```
class Locationable < ...
   belongs_to :location
end

class Lodging < ...
   belongs_to :location
end

class Transportation < ...
   belongs_to start_location, class_name: :Location
   belongs_to end_location, class_name: :Location
end
```

or course to keep the db more clean you can use `through` key for (for example) `Lodging` class, but only then if you already have an assotiation in it:

```
class Locationable < ...
   belongs_to :location
end

class Lodging < ...
   belongs_to :locationable
   has_one :location, through: :locationable
end
```